# MySql find data in one table based on conditions of two other tables

Tags: php, mysql, join

Help me out with this query:
I have 3 tables with this structure.

**items_to_groups** (item_id | group_id)

**item_to_regions** (item_id | region_id)

**items** [a bunch of columns]

I need to select every row on the ***item*** table that has an item_id match on **item_to_groups** table WHERE *group = x* AND  has an item_id match on **item_to_regions** table WHERE *region = y*

Currently the code I have is a horrible subquery with loops and all.

What would be a better way of doing this? 
I've thought about JOIN and such, but can't really get my head around on how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT bunch_of_columns
FROM items i 
INNER JOIN items_to_groups ig ON i.id=ig.item_id
INNER JOIN items_to_regions ir on i.id=ir.item_d
WHERE ir.region_id=y
AND ig.group_id=x
```

Have a look at the [JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/join.html) documentation on MySQL. Joins are important for relational databases. 
As you said you have a hard time grasping joins, have a look at [A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) by Jeff Atwood. Maybe it helps.

Comment: I have trust me. But these JOINS are my archenemy. 
I need these real life situations to get my head around it. Thanks.

Comment: @Ericko edited my answer to include one more link to codinghorror. Have a look at it :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT colums 
FROM items 
INNER JOIN items_to_groups ON items.item_id = items_to_groups.item_id AND group_id = x 
INNER JOIN items_to_regions ON items.item_id = items_to_regions.item_id AND region_id = y
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM items
JOIN items_to_groups ON (items.item_id = items_to_groups.item_id AND group_id = ?)
JOIN items_to_regions ON (items.item_id = items_to_regions.item_id AND region_id = ?)
GROUP BY items.item_id
```