# SQL query to return results from one table based on data joined from two other tables?

Tags: mysql, join

I have a site with guitar lessons (drupal). I have a content type lesson that contains exercise content types. Exercises reference a lesson nid through a specific table that is used to handle lesson-exercise relations. Exercises have images (known as tab), and the images are handled via a file table. For a given lesson, I am trying to build an SQL query that returns the images associated with a lesson's exercises, and then choose one at random. I know it will amount to a join of some sort, but I have no idea if it will be a left, inner, or some combination.

The relevant columns in the relevant tables are

1. The table that is used to link exercises to a lesson (lesson). field_lesson_target_id is lesson id, entity_id is exercise id.
2. The image field for exercises (tab). entity_id is exercise id, field_tab_fid is the file id.
3. The file table (file) fid is the file id, which in this case would relate to field_tab_fid in the tab table.

Here is the fiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dbf63

Comment: Can you do the random picking of images in your app layer? It is far easier than in the query.

Comment: Yes, I can randomize the results later

Comment: SELECT l.*, t.*, f.* FROM lesson as l 
LEFT JOIN tab as t ON t.entity_id = l.entity_id 
LEFT JOIN file as f ON f.fid = t.field_tab_fid 
WHERE l.entity_id = '693'

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dbf63/3

Comment: Your query is returning a file for one exercise with exercise id 693. In my example, lesson id is 672 and so the query has to return all images of all exercises that reference lesson 672. My SQL below seems to work, but I haven't tested yet when there is data for various lessons, exercises.

Answer (score 0):

After reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6875832/mysql-find-data-in-one-table-based-on-conditions-of-two-other-tables), perhaps this is what I need?

```
SELECT * 
FROM file f
INNER JOIN tab t on t.field_tab_fid = f.fid
INNER JOIN lesson l ON l.entity_id = t.entity_id
WHERE l.field_lesson_target_id = 672
```

I am just not sure if my situation dictates the same type of join. And in the example, there are two conditions, but seems in my case there is one.

fiddle:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dbf63/4